# Npm package for run specific entry

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use webpack to bundle all js for a multi page app. Is there a package that can help "routing" which script should run on page load? For example adding an atribute to body element like "data-load-entry"?

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) can be used to generate HTML files that load your JS bundle.

By combining [Generating Multiple HTML Files](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files) and [Writing Your Own Templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates), you should be able to generate multiple HTML files that are customized so the code in your bundle can determine what to run.